# How can I create a database using pymssql

Tags: python, sql, linux, pymssql

Im trying to create a database using pymssql and im getting this error.

```
cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s;" % self.getsql('dbname'), conn)
```

gives

```
*** OperationalError: (226, 'CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-
statement transaction.DB-Lib error message 226, severity 16:\\nGeneral SQL Serve
r error: Check messages from the SQL Server\\n')
```

What does this mean ??

Comment: Try `cur.execute("create database %s" % (self.getsql('dbname'),), conn)`, also try it without the `getsql` call.

Comment: If you are running other statements before your `CREATE DATABASE` one, you may need to `commit()` the current transaction before running it.

Answer (score 10):

The issue was that cur.execute starts a transaction every time, but 'CREATE DATABASE' operation cannot be excuted within a transaction

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/594ff024-8af6-40b3-89e0-53edb3ad7245

```
>>> connection.autocommit(True)
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE Foo")
>>> connection.autocommit(False)
```

This to works. Strangely its not documented in pymssql ... hmmm

Comment: FWIW, [pyodbc also automatically starts transactions](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management), so setting autocommit True solves this for pyodbc too.

Comment: yes this also worked for me. Strangely if you toggle autocommit before and after the create statement it does work.

Comment: How would you provide the `server`, `user`, `password` ? in `connection`